# How do I set an ADO.NET Entity Framework connection string via the Windows Azure (Preview) Management Portal?

Tags: entity-framework, deployment, azure, connection-string, azure-web-app-service

In the Windows Azure (Preview) Management Portal you can change the configuration options for web sites (see http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-configure-websites/#howtochangeconfig).

I currently set the connection string for my ADO.NET Entity Framework connection via Web.Release.Config, but I want to set it via the Management Portal, but no matter what I use, I always end up with the following error:

> The specified named connection is either not found in the
>   configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider,
>   or not valid.

It does work for regular connection strings, ie without the metadata key defining metadata and mapping information (csdl, ssdl, msl).

Here's what I do:

I go to https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/WebsiteExtension/Website/[MY-STAGING-SITE-NAME]/configure

Under "connection strings" I have a key named "ApplicationServices" that looks like this:

> Server=tcp:xxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=xxxxx;User
>   ID=xxxxx@xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection
>   Timeout=30;

This one works.

I have another key for the Entity Framework connection. Let's call that one FooBarContext. It looks like this:

> metadata=res://*/Models.FooBarContext.csdl|res://*/Models.FooBarContext.ssdl|res://*/Models.FooBarContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider
>   connection
>   string="Server=tcp:fooserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=foobar;User
>   ID=myname@fooserver;Password=xxxxxxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection
>   Timeout=30;"

This one causes the error described above. It is copied from the **working** value in  Web.Release.Config, with the &quot; replaced by a ".

I have tried other variations: with the &quot; untouched, with metadata appended at the end, but to no avail. I have reproduced the problem with a second website.

Comment: First check whether you see the connection string in `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` (i.e. write it to webpage). 

The name should be present in `web.config`, Azure WS will replace it with the value defined in portal (it will not add new if it's not there). The double quotes `"` work fine through portal, you don't have to deal with that.

Comment: @cincura.net I have run the following test: set the values in web.config to "[SET ON manage.windowsazure.com]". When I deploy and write out the values from System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings they are replaced by the values set via manage.windowsazure.com.  So the mechanism works, but the problem remains that the format of the EF connection string is not recognized.

Comment: @cincura.net Do you have an (anonymized) example of a working EF connection string that is set via manage.windowsazure.com?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The solution for my problem was selecting **"Custom"** instead of **"SQL Azure"** from the "SQL Azure / SQL Server / MySQL / Custom" selector for the Entity Framework connection string, even though the database does run on SQL Azure.

[Edit] From a popular comment by @matthew-steeples below:

> I would add to this for anyone else having the same issue is that
>   sometimes the config file will have `&quot;` instead of `"`, and the Azure
>   Websites needs those to be changed to `"`

Comment: All I would add to this for anyone else having the same issue is that sometimes the config file will have &quot; instead of ", and the Azure Websites needs those to be changed to "

Comment: sweet jesus this just bought me a couple hours sleep, beer on me, all you can drink, to Frank and Matthew anytime you guys visit San Diego!!

Comment: I can't believe I've just had this problem, searched for the issue, and found that my own comment was the thing that needed fixing!

Comment: But, guys, then where do you specify the provider? As what sounds like good practice to us, we strip development connection strings from the release `Web.config` which is thus completely devoid of any connection information. Then, we configure it per deployment slot in the panel; which works great except for when we need a custom provider. I assume it works for all of you because the development info is deployed to the production server, then the connection string is overriden but not the provider name. Is this correct?

Comment: I lost two days of work because I haven't selected 'custom' on that stupid option. Thank you Frank.

Comment: By the way, the 'Custom' setting they are talking about is in a dropdown in Azure as the last column for the connection string table. I thought It was some configuration at first from when I first setup EF and had no clue it was right there.

Comment: @tne I saw nobody answered you here, I think you are confusing things -- the ProviderName is not specific to Development in many cases. What you do is create a Web.Release.Config that has the XDT Transformations in them. You can look this up online, here is an example of the transformation we use in production:

<add name="defaultConnection" connectionString="dummy" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />

This replaces the connectionString with the word "dummy" and azure overrides.

Comment: The connectionString can be overridden by a value set in the Azure portal but the 'providerName' still comes from the web.config when you enter a "Custom" connection string in the portal. So, as @dmarlow describes in his answer, you do need to keep a dummy connection string in the web.config file that you publish to Azure.

Comment: @MatthewSteeples that comment should be part of the answer. Also, don't forget to press save at the top of the Azure interface after changing the value in the connection string!

Answer (score 14):

[image]

Replace

```
&quot;
```

with

```
"
```

In the connection string.

Comment: Keep in mind that this post is a few years old. I just tried double quote instead of &quot; and it does work.

Answer (score 5):

Not only did I have to use double quotes (or single quotes) instead of `&quot;` (and select Custom for the type) but I also had to make sure there was a dummy value in my transform config. I was replacing the entire connectionStrings node, but decided to keep that and add this:

```
<add xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="FooBarEntities" connectionString="temp" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Without this, I was getting the following error:

`The connection string 'FooBarEntities' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute.`

Answer (score 0):

Beside answers above, there are 2 very important things:

1. You should remove "name=" from "name=connectionString"
   in constructor:

> public MyEntities(string connectionString)
>                   : base($"name={connectionString}")
>               {
>               }

2. You should leave "duplicate" of connection string in app.config, but
   replace connection string with dummy text, correct connection string
   will be loaded from Azure. That's needed for providerName part.
   Please read:
   https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/07/05/update-connection-string-for-entity-framework-in-azure-web-app-settings/comment-page-1/

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I solved, putting in the web.config this connectionstring:

```
<add name="eManagerTurModelConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ORM.eManagerFinanceModel.csdl|res://*/ORM.eManagerFinanceModel.ssdl|res://*/ORM.eManagerFinanceModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=<server>.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=eManagerTur;Integrated Security=False;User ID=<user>;Password=<Password>;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

And after I removed the connectionstring of my website, worked, because it was not getting the connection string that I added in my web.config.

English bad... =)