# Failing to get EF connection string to work when setup in Azure's management portal?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I am using ASP.NET MVC4 deployed on WebApps, EF6, Azure SQL Database

I have two connectionstrings, one direct to the DB and one that is needed as I am using Entity Framework. If I setup the first via Azure and leave the EF string in web.config, all works fine. Once I try to move the EF connectionstring to Azure, it breaks.

I have tried to follow all the posts on how to setup an EF connection string in Azure Management Portal, and the advice seems to be to use the following:

In Management Portal:

Name:

```
EFConnectionString
```

Value:

```
metadata=res://MyModel/model.csdl|res://MyModel/model.ssdl|res://MyModel/model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1234;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;User ID=Admin@myserver.database.windows.net;Password=12345678"
```

SQL Database:

```
Custom
```

Note:

```
&quot; is replaced by " in the Azure string.
```

In Web.config I still need the following:

```
<add name="EFConnectionString" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

I have changed certain details in the connectionstring for security reasons, but the true string does work fine in Web.config.

However when I do attempt the above, I get :

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

Further Log error message:

```
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.
```

Any help appreciated. I am trying to do this to enhance the security of stored passwords for accessing DB on Azures, as I understand that setting them up via the portal encrypts them.

Thanks.

Comment: this all looks really strange to me. why does your connection string in one config use System.Data.EntityClient, in the other one SqlClient? why is the port (I assume that's what 1234 is) separated by a ',' instead of a ':'?

Comment: Borrowing a suggestion from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459748/how-do-i-set-an-ado-net-entity-framework-connection-string-via-the-windows-azure

First check whether you see the connection string in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings (i.e. write it to webpage). The name should be present in web.config, Azure WS will replace it with the value defined in portal (it will not add new if it's not there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check your deployment. I've run in a similar problem, and after a couple of hours struggling I found out that I was deploying without actually sending connection strings, falling back to whatever was in the portal config... the others keys in the we.config were being sent over, but the conn strings weren't... after I properly set it up on the portal, everything went back to normal...