# Database Connection Problem - Azure MySql Database Server from .net core 3.1

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-mysql-database

-- Background:
I am using asp.net mvc project with 3.1 .net core.
I have azure setup for hosting it in app service.
For Database, I have mysql database server set up on Azure (version 5.7).

-- Problem:
I am using basic connection string when connecting to mysql database. But it is not working for hosted application.

- When I connect the azure hosted database server locally using WorkBench, and run the program (locally), it 'works'. (WorkBench connection has Ssl = required and SSL cert File attached.)
- But when I publish the same code with same connectionString, it is not working.

IS IT BCZ OF:

- I am using 5.7 azure mysql database server?
  (To update the version, do I need to create new mysql server on azure and pay $20? Because Mycrosoft documentation says there is 'Upgrade' option on overview. But there is not. Or might for higher subscription. Any suggestions?)
- If the reason is I am missing mentioning ssl certi on hosted platform, how can I add it? Do I need to get storage to store that certificate? How can I mention that path in connectionString?
- Any other reason for this problem?

I checked YouTube, Microsoft documents, And Google but didn't find solution.

UPDATE:

Libraries used:

MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.X

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.X

MySql-Connector-Net 8.0.X

Connection String used:  "Server=.mysql.database.azure.com;Port=3306;Database=;Uid=;Pwd=;"

Comment: You didn't post any code, connection string, exceptions or explain what libraries you use, so we can only guess. .NET Core 3.1 has reached End-of-Life. The oldest supported version is .NET 6, supported until 2024. MySQL 5.7 is old too, and Oracle's Connector/NET is full of problems in even the most basic things. More people use the truly open source [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) package than Oracle's buggy driver

Comment: You need to provide some code and sample connection strings as @Panagoitis pointed out. Try to hard code your connection string instead of adding that to `web.config` to avoid any other dependencies. The other reason would be you are missing some configuration in Azure website settings, check out [this[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591130/deploying-to-azure-cannot-connect-to-database).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. And I am sorry for not providing libraries and connection string. I added it now.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: It was cause of incomplete networking. I had to allow other azure services to connect that server. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: And error was 404!

Comment: @JemsChaudhary If the above issue resolved with stated approach, post it as an answer so that it will help other community members.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
It was unable to connect because of incomplete networking.

I had to allow other azure services to connect that server.

Thanks for your comments.